# Hide content based on URL string (PHP)

Tags: php, magento

I've signed up to one of those affiliate sites to help drive traffic to my online store. They've asked that I hide the telephone number on my site for referring traffic.

All traffic that they refer will append any of my site urls with something like '?affiliate'.

Does anyone know how I can hide content on a page if a URL contains '?affiliate' but show it if the URL does not contain this text?

I'm using the Magento system, in case that makes a difference. :D

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (!array_key_exists('affiliate', $_GET)) {
    //show telephone number
}
```

`empty` will fail here because the value of `$_GET['affiliate']` will be `""`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried using this as follows. But it always shows the number. I need it to show the number by default, unless the url contains affiliate.

if (!array_key_exists('affiliate', $_GET)) {
    echo "<p>020 XXXXXX</p>";
}

Comment: @Neil WHat you did was correct. Maybe the query string is malformed, e.g. the url already contained a query string and the affiliate added "?affiliate" instead of "&affiliate"?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['affiliate'])) {
    // don't show
}
else {
    // show telephone number
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['affiliate']))
{
  // hide the content now
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail: The manual on isset() says *"Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL."* `affiliate` will be null in this case.

Comment: @Pekka I was actually wrong there. It will be `""`. This is also correct.

Comment: @Artefacto you're right, `isset()` indeed works. I stand corrected!

Comment: @Pekka I actually was induced in error with a phpinfo page, which showed "no value", which I assumed mean NULL.